# Laravel routes error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Here is two routes that I have:

```
Route::resource('tournament/{tourId}/phase/{phaseId}/bets', 'PhaseController@getPhaseBets');
Route::resource('tournament/{tourId}/phase/{phaseId}', 'PhaseController@getPhaseInfo');
```

But I am getting this exception when trying to run any GET api:

```
Route pattern "/api/tournament/{tourId}/phase/{phaseId}/{{phaseId}}" cannot reference variable name "phaseId" more than once.
```

From did it get `{{phaseId}}` ? why I am getting this error?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

Since you are defining routes directly pointing to your controller actions, you should be using:

```
Route::get('tournament/{tourId}/phase/{phaseId}/bets', 'PhaseController@getPhaseBets');
Route::get('tournament/{tourId}/phase/{phaseId}', 'PhaseController@getPhaseInfo');
```

---

**Longer version:**

To use `Route::resource()` you should be following the docs in [Resource Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers). E.g:

```
Route::resource('phase', 'PhaseController');
```

Which will generate route urls like:

```
/tournament/{tourId}/phase/{phaseId}/bets
/tournament/{tourId}/phase/{phaseId}/bets/{resource_id}
/tournament/{tourId}/phase/{phaseId}/bets/{resource_id}/edit
/tournament/{tourId}/phase/{phaseId}/bets/create
```

You would see that now instead of having one parameter for the resource id, the routes now have up to 3 parameters. That confuses Laravel up on which one it should use as the resource id.

Since you are defining routes directly pointing to your controller actions, you should be using:

```
Route::get('tournament/{tourId}/phase/{phaseId}/bets', 'PhaseController@getPhaseBets');
Route::get('tournament/{tourId}/phase/{phaseId}', 'PhaseController@getPhaseInfo');
```

If you'd still like to use resource controllers you'll need to change your code to something like this.

```
Route::resource('phase', 'PhaseController');
Route::resource('bet', 'BetController');
```

and in your controller files:

*PhaseController.php:*

```
class PhaseController extends BaseController
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        // Your original PhaseController@getPhaseInfo() here
    }
}
```

*BetController.php:*

```
class BetController extends BaseController
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        // Your original PhaseController@getPhaseBets() here
    }
}
```

And reference your urls like this:

```
/phase/your_phase_id
/bet/your_bet_id
```

Obviously this might not totally suit your requirements. If you could explain a little bit of the relationships between tournaments, phases, bets, and what you're trying to achieve, maybe we can suggest a better way.

Comment: but this are resources, why cant I use it like I posted?

Comment: I've updated my answer a little bit. Basically you're not conforming to how Laravel generate routes for resource controller as documented in http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers. The way you define your routes with extra variables like {tourId} and {phaseId} confuses Laravel up.

Comment: @vlio20 updated a little more, let me know if you need more info or not :)